# Show name of Month

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

This is my output

[image]

```
select name as product, avg(OrderQty) as average, OrderDate
from Production.Product
join Sales.SalesOrderDetail on SalesOrderDetail.ProductID = Product.ProductID
join Sales.SalesOrderHeader on SalesOrderHeader.SalesOrderID = SalesOrderDetail.SalesOrderID
where OrderDate like '%2011%'
group by Name, OrderDate
```

I want to change order Date to the month for example

2011-10-24 00.00.00.000 ==> october

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Two side notes: **(1)** When working with several tables, you should give each an alias and qualify each column in your query with its table alias. **(2)** `LIKE` is a string function that you should not invoke on a date. Make this `where year(OrderDate) = 2011` or `where OrderDate >= '20110101' and OrderDate < '20120101'`. The latter expression may make use of an index. We must use string literals for the dates, though, because SQL Server does not support date literals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `datename()` in SQL Server to get name of the month.

```
select 
   datename(month, orderDate) AS monthName
from yourTable
```